# Mutating a field and performing a lookup in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I have two models, `Cart` and `Incode`. `Cart` has a field called `incode_txt` which gets populated with an alphanumeric string such as `5td`

When this happens, I have a mutator to make sure the string gets converted to uppercase as so:

```
        return Attribute::make(
            set: fn (string $value) => strtoupper($value)
        );
```

This is done following the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for defining mutators. So far so good.

However, I also have another field on the `Cart` model called `address_incode_id`. Every time `incode_txt` is set, I want to perform a search on the `Incode` model using the same `$value` like this:

```
$incode = Incode::where('name', '=', $value)
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $value[0] . '%')
    ->first();
```

I then want $incode->id to be saved to the address_incode_id field on the `Cart` model.

My question: Can I somehow merge these two actions into the same mutator and, if so, is it even a good idea to do so? I'd like to know what the correct way to achieve something like this is. The Laravel docs has a piece about [Mutating Multiple Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#mutating-multiple-attributes) but it doesn't seem relevant to my use case.

Comment: You can simply implement an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers) on your `Encode` model which you can listen on `created` event, then perform a query on `Cart` model and save the `id`. or do it more complex way and put it on [Event Listener](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events)

Comment: There won't be any create (or other) event on the `Incode` model because it's just being read from, not written to. What you suggested would work if I listened on the `Cart` model though. The only thing is that I don't need to do this *every* time `Cart` is updated so I was hoping for a way just to run the action specifically when `incode_txt` on `Cart` was being mutated.

Comment: yeah, I think I mixed your models out, but your best option is Observer or Event Listener, you can listen for `updated` event and check a specific column if `isDirty()`, check out the documentation, everything you need to get you started are all there

Comment: actually, an unconventional method, was to simply call a different function in your mutator for that query you want to perform, which includes that `strtoupper`. you can can implement an anonymous function, or add another method in your Model to perform the same thing which you can call instead.

Comment: Thanks for the options! I've had a play about with the ways you suggested and I think that an Observer in conjunction with `isDirty()` id the best way to solve this. Please feel free to post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full exmaple using Observers

Generate an Observer

```
php artisan make:observer CartObserver --model=Cart
```

edit the generated file in `app/Observers/CartObserver.php`

an example below that only observe updated event, the check if the specific attribute is modified using `isDirty`

```
use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Incode;

class CartObserver  {

public $afterCommit = true; //trigger after commit

public function updated(Cart $cart) {

    if ( $cart->isDirty('incode_txt') ) {
        
        $incode = Incode::where('name', $cart->incode_txt)
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $cart->incode_txt . '%')->first();


        if ( $incode ) {

            /* $cart->fill([
                'address_incode_id' => $incode->id;
            ]); */

            $cart->address_incode_id =  $incode->id;
            $cart->saveQuietly();

            // Otherwise create a job that update the Card model quietly

        }
            

    }

}
```

}

After that, don't forget to add your observer in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` `boot` method

```
use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Observers\CartObserver;
```

and on `boot`

```
Cart::observe(CartObserver::class);
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I edited your answer to correct a couple of typos and also to have it update the `Cart` model, not `Incode` as per my original question. Then, because of this update, it was necessary to change `update` to `fill` to prevent an infinite loop from the observer. Thanks again for helping me with this!

Comment: Actually, I'm also thinking it may be necessary to use `$cart->unsetEventDispatcher();` to stop an infinite loop too. What do you think?

Comment: @Joseph, I updated my answer, try the `saveQuietly` method. I didn't realize you are updating a model you are listening which could potentially raise an issue, You could also dispatch a Job, to update the model quitely if you keep getting issue

Comment: @Joseph, yes, you can also try calling `$cart->unsetEventDispatcher();` before the update statement,

Comment: actually, now that I think about it, since you are updating the same model you are listening, you can probably just use the `updating` or I think there is `saving` listener then an assign the attribute value into it to modify before it gets saved.

Comment: Aah, yes, you're right! I can use `updating` and then just issue `$cart->address_incode_id =  $incode->id;` and it gets included in the update without a second `$cart->save()` being needed. I think that this is really the best solution to the problem as it reduces the number of database queries too.